# Making sure fields are initialized out of constructor

Tags: java

Edit: Sorry for my previous question, the *final* keyword will confusing you, It's not appropriate. And sorry for my poor English too.

-----Question------

Assume I have a model class without any constructor, because I need to initialize it within many different logic. **But** i have a *notnull* keyword.

```
public class Model {
    public notnull String name;
    public notnull String address;
    public notnull int age;
}
```

And I need to use it in different place but keep checking if all *notnull* fields were initialized **in compile time**

```
Model m = new Model();
m.name = "Hello";
m.age = 15;
// syntax error, you should set Model.address
```

Or

```
Model m1 = new Model();
m1.address = "World";
m1.age = 20;
// syntax error, you should set Model.name
```

How can I achieve that in java?
Thx.

Comment: I'm confused. If they're final, you *have to* initialize them all in the constructor.

Comment: you need to initialize them either when you declare them as `final String a = "A"`, in EACH constructor as `a = "A"` or within an instance initializer block as `{ a = "A" }`, otherwise you get a compile time error. The way you do currently have it set up the `final` wouldn´t make sense as you are not in need to initialize them which would contradict what the `final` is there for.

Comment: and "But I have a new keyword say notnull" lol..

Comment: For the edit: that´s java not an sql table. there is no `notNull` or something similar in java. The most similar you can have is the `final`, which dooms you to initialize, where `null` isn´t forbidden...

Comment: @RC. The keyword *final* will make others teaching me java basic gramer. And that's not i'm asking ;-P

Comment: Now you changed your question from `final` to `not null`. This breaks previously given answers ... and your title still refer to final fields

Comment: I think maybe you want a constructor with three parameters?  `public Model(String name, String address, int age) { ... }` and initialize your fields from the parameters.  I don't know, it's really hard to tell what you want.

Comment: @Harmlezz Sorry for confusing you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the Builder Pattern. There are number of articles that you can find on the internet on how to use it. This is one example https://jlordiales.me/2012/12/13/the-builder-pattern-in-practice/. Using the Builder pattern you can validate if certain fields are set or not and throw exception if there are not.

Comment: This is probably not an appropriate answer for someone who's still learning the basics of Java.

Comment: @ajb Actually I have such like JSON parser, HTTP Server, and many other tools built by myself with pure java. I mean it's not a basics question I think ;-P

Comment: @tabiul Thanks for your answer, I'm expecting more grammar level solution (check in compile time). Your answer is actually a Factory Design Pattern, means I should write another Class and It won't check in compile time.

Comment: ah ok, so you want to have some sort of new keyword `notnull`. Hmm, I maybe wrong but I think what you want is not possible in Java. Maybe you should use Scala :) as over there there is `Case Class` and you can use `val` and `var`

Comment: @G.Bob not possible with keywords but you can use annotations. Not sure what IDE you are using but Intellij IDEA has built in `@NotNull` and `@Nullable` annotations also you can built your own annotations and annotation processors for other IDEs. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2386013/3133545

Comment: @G.Bob My apologies. It's hard to tell sometimes.

Comment: @Onur Thanks, your answer is quite helpful for this question.

Answer (score 2):

> assume I have a model class without any constractor

This is not possible. Every class has a constructor. If you do not define one you end up with the default constructor. In your case:

```
public Model() {
    super();
}
```

> checking if all final field were initialized

First, final fields must be initialized, otherwise the compiler will not compile. Hence you have to have to initialize final fields either:

- in the constructor
- when declaring the final field

**Constructor Initialization**

```
public final String name;
public final int age;

public Model() {
    this.name = "Hello";
    this.age = 13;
}
```

**Declaration Initialization**

```
public final String name = "Hello";
public final int age = 13;

public Model() {
    super();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you *seems* to want with something like this:

```
public class Model {
    private final String name;
    private final String address;
    private final int age;

    public Model(final String name, final String address, final int age) {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("please provide a name");
        }
        if (address == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("please provide an address");
        }
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // getters
}
```

Usage:

```
new Model("World", "Some address", 20) // OK
new Model("World", null, 20) // Exception because null address.
```

Answer (score 0):

If only final :
You can either instantiate them where you declare or instantiate inside the constructor.

If final + static:
You MUST instantiate them where you declared.

So since they are not static you need to instantiate where you specified them or in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> Assume I have a model class without any constructor because I need to
>   initialize it within many different logic. But I have a notnull
>   keyword.

You need to note that **even if you don't write any constructor, the compiler will provide a default no-argument constructor** which will initialize all fields in the object to the default values automatically (i.e., `String` types to `null` and `int` types to zero values, etc..)

---

The **class constructor is a right place to validate all mandatory fields are provided or not**, so **create your own constructor to check all mandatory fields** are passed in during the object creation:

```
public class Model {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int age;

    public Model(String name, String address, int age) {
         if(name == null) { 
               throw new IllegalArgumentException(" Name is mandatory ");
         } 
         if(address == null) { 
               throw new IllegalArgumentException(" Address is mandatory ");
         }
         if(age < 0) { 
               throw new IllegalArgumentException(" Age is Invalid ");
         }
         this.name = name;
         this.address = address;
         this.age = age;
    }
   //Add getters and setters
}
```

---

Also, **encapsulate the data** of your `Model` class by marking your fields `private` (shown above).